# Seleccionar solo ciertas hojas de excel y unirlas en un solo dataframe en r?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un libro de *Excel* el cual contiene varias hojas de cálculo, de las cuales solo necesito **importar 12 hojas** y **unirlas** en un solo data `frame`.

Las hojas que deseo unir son las siguientes: 1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, 5D, 6D, 7D, 8D, 9D, 10D, 11D, 12D

[Adjunto enlace para descargar el archivo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lNtGtD4nU3aDpEEwx42K9ghsIhZbBeGW/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103692610363053831812&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es usar alguna función para poder leer el excel (te recomiendo la librería openxlsx)

```
library(openxlsx)

nombre_archivo = "nombre_archivo.xlsx"
nombre_hojas = c("1D", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "11D", "12D")

do.call(rbind,lapply(nombre_hojas,  function(x)read.xlsx(nombre_archivo, sheet = x)))
```

1. Definir nombre del archivo y las hojas a leer
2. con lapply lees cada hoja con la funcion read.xlsx lo cual retornara una lista con cada hoja
3. con do.call aplicamos rbind para concatenar cada elemento de la lista y juntarlo en un unico

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, una última consulta: Me podrías indicar que hace esta parte del código:
function(x)read.xlsx(nombre_archivo, sheet = x)
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo que hace especificamente esa parte es leer el excel en cuestion pero la hoja ira variando en funcion de las que indiques en nombre_hojas y la manera de que vaya variando es igualar sheet = x

Comment: Un favor más, cómo hago para que en cada dataframe me aparezca el nombre de la hoja?

Comment: Podrias agregarlo asi:

do.call(rbind,lapply(nombre_hojas,  function(x)read.xlsx(nombre_archivo, sheet = x) %>% mutate(hoja = x)))